# condensing code/script in head tags

Tags: javascript

I have 3 scripts hard-coded in my head tags which all target different elements in my site. However most of them are based on similar events (when mouse scrolls, etc) I am wondering if it could be combined/condensed at all. I've tried but can't seem to make it any smaller while keeping functionality.

script 1 - animates #nav away when user scrolls dwn, brings it back when scrolled up

script 2 - animates away a second menu (#nav-BN) on < 768px screens when user scrolls up or down

script 3 - hides and shows a div/button > 768px screens, hides it if smaller

```
<script>
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
hasScrolled();
didScroll = false;
}
 }, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
return;

if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
// Scroll Down
$('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
// Scroll Up
if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
$('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}
}
lastScrollTop = st;
}
</script>


<script>
var lastPos=0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        $('#nav-BN').addClass('BN-nav-hide').removeClass('BN-nav-show');

clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
$.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $('#nav-BN').addClass('BN-nav-show').removeClass('BN-nav-hide');
}, 250));
}
});
</script>


<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 200)) {
        $("#up-btn").fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $("#up-btn").fadeOut(500);
    }
    } else {
       $("#up-btn").fadeOut(250);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might notice some important things:

- Replace multiple jQuery search by storing the objects in variables
- Is not necessary to have two classes for hidden and shown, you can have one class named 'active' instead of BN-nav-show, and in case that class is missing it should be NB-nav-hide
- if (window.innerWidth > 768) and (window.innerWidth < 768) can be merged into one unique structure:

  if(){
  } else {
  }

This should help

```
   <script>
      var didScroll;
      var lastScrollTop = 0;
      var delta = 5;
      var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();
      var $window = $(window);
      var $upBtn = $("#up-btn")

      var lastPos=0;
      window.scroll(function(event) {
        didScroll = true;
        var $navBN = $('#nav-BN');

        if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
          if ($window.scrollTop() + window .height() > ($(document).height() - 200)) {
            upBtn.fadeIn(500);
          } else {
            upBtn.fadeOut(500);
          }
        } else {
          navBN.removeClass('active');    
          clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
          $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
            navBN.addClass('active');
          }, 250));

          upBtn.fadeOut(250);
        }

      });

      function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;

        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
          // Scroll Down
          $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        } else {
          // Scroll Up
          if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
          }
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
      }


    setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
      }
    }, 250);

</script>
```

Comment: none of the functionality works when using the code you provided, It is not throwing any errors but none of the functionality is working

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with toggle classes, then you can do that

https://jsfiddle.net/9yhug2qg/1/

```js
var windowST, navBar, navBarHeight;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  windowST = $(window).scrollTop();
  navBar = $('.navbar');
  navBarHeight = parseInt(navBar.height());

  if (windowST > navBarHeight) {
    $(navBar).addClass('out-of-area');
  } else {
    $(navBar).removeClass("out-of-area");
  }
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0;padding: 0; }

body { height: 700vh; }

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #0ff;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 1s ease
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  visibility: visible;
  width:calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar.out-of-area {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.navbar > .nav_btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #151515;
  right: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar > .nav_btn { visibility: visible; }
  ul { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <nav class="nav_btn"></nav>
    <ul></ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is my code the menu div comes down whenever the user scrolls up not just when they reach the top